# muon neutrino momentum distribution

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos

muon neutrino momentum distribution

I have read the public data of T2K ,KEK to find this subject, I'm curiously that it's coincides with my prediction perfectly: The neutrino get its momemtum by its effect-partner, which is obvious in the reactional formula, especialy that by me. You can find the figures [Here](http://blog.sciencenet.cn/home.php?mod=space&uid=595492&do=blog&id=462424) ( htis link is a blog including the detialed idea) the first is the radium function of e, the second cut from paper from the lab, the third is the momemtum spectrum. Do any one find the simlar distribution of other particle? I just work on Hep just for a few months.

Comment: it is not possible to find the plots from your link, since the blog is in chinese. I would like to understand what you are asking, but it is very hard. Are you talking of the momentum spectrum of the neutrino in the decay of the muon to an electron, and electron neutrino, and a muon neutrino? In the center of mass system? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon#Muon_decay .

Answer (score 3):

Do you understand how neutrino beams are made for such experiments?

The beam from some more mundane particle accelerator is used to direct high energy particles (often protons) into a target which generates a spray of assorted products containing many pions and kaons. This secondary beam is filtered and selected for momentum by passing it through collimators and dipole magnets; focused using a "horn"; and allowed to propogate down another beam-line where the hadrons decay.

The decay products include many neutrinos, and relativity means that most of them are going mostly in the direction of the final beam-line. Their momentum distribution is a function of the hadrons beam's momentum (which can be selected), the hadron beams compositions, the decay kinematics of pions and kaons, and the angle relative the deca beam-line at which you place your detector.

Finally, the momentum distribution of the neutrinos ***that react*** in your detector also has a factor due to the energy dependence of the neutrino interaction cross-section.

Comment: These neutrino come from muon that's in a speed. If the speed of muon is given then the speed distribution of its neutrinos can be clculated by Realtive theory, but the distribution of muon's speed must be multiplied. Can the distribution neutrino from a single muon can be isolated? I need this data.